# OnItemDataBound for ListView bounded to a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, listview

When i bound a `ListView` to a `List<variable>`,when the function of the `OnItemDataBound` is runnng, i can get the `ListView`'s properties like this:

```
((variable)e.Item.DataItem).property
```

now, when i bound the `ListView` to a `DataTable`, how can i get the properies? what do i put in the bracket:`((`**what do i put here**`)e.Item.DataItem).property`?

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.Item.DataItem will be a DataRow so something like this should work:

```
((DataRow)e.Item.DataItem)["YourColumnName"]
```

Comment: the web developer told me to change it to 'DataRowView', it was close and you got me there so thanks!